python-json-logger unique ID per request
I think this is specific to the python-json-logger package, and not something for Stack Overflow, but I guess I'll post here, just in case someone has run across this before.
I have a request to have a unique ID in the logs "per request".
I can reproduce the problem that I'm trying to solve by this loop:
    for i in range(3):
        update_logger(__name__) # this is where I try to set a unique ID for all log messages going forward:
        # I want each of these messages to have the SAME unique_id
        logger.info('loop start')
        logger.info(f'loop: {i}')
        logger.info('loop end')

I'm hoping to have something like:
{"message": "loop start", "request_id": "XXX"}
{"message": "loop: 0", "request_id": "XXX"}
{"message": "loop end", "request_id": "XXX"}
{"message": "loop start", "request_id": "YYY"}
{"message": "loop: 1", "request_id": "YYY"}
{"message": "loop end", "request_id": "YYY"}
{"message": "loop start", "request_id": "ZZZ"}
{"message": "loop: 2", "request_id": "ZZZ"}
{"message": "loop end", "request_id": "ZZZ"}

But instead I'm getting a unique ID PER message:
{"message": "loop start", "request_id": "aaa1f7986f144601af5a533baee1aca7"}
{"message": "loop: 0", "request_id": "afd7c033339a4030adcfb6eff78a007f"}
{"message": "loop end", "request_id": "63c51ca47afc4f73920c0e6998bf61ac"}
{"message": "loop start", "request_id": "21484da3aa0b46559310cbef3b6c5391"}
{"message": "loop: 1", "request_id": "67bdb9a7944b479aac2c4f86bef2fd4c"}
{"message": "loop end", "request_id": "8d0f7469a34b405ba6adf0cf51118c33"}
{"message": "loop start", "request_id": "89a4387b10634d268b2fbe0fd35ce677"}
{"message": "loop: 2", "request_id": "bf4099ed93f046628baa18a8201ca201"}
{"message": "loop end", "request_id": "60777e3113b84daabd12b003384e4fb8"}

My full code is like this:
#from utilities.logs import get_logger
import logging
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger
import uuid


class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        log_record['request_id'] = uuid.uuid4().hex


def get_logger(logger_name):
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = CustomJsonFormatter('%(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger


def update_logger(logger_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    myhandler = logger.handlers[0]
    myhandler.setFormatter(CustomJsonFormatter('%(message)s'))


logger = get_logger(__name__)


def main():
    for i in range(3):
        update_logger(__name__)
        # I want each of these messages to have the SAME unique_id
        logger.info('loop start')
        logger.info(f'loop: {i}')
        logger.info('loop end')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


I was hoping the function add_fields would be called just once, when I'm setting the formatter, but it looks like it's called every time I print a log message.
Is there a way to do this with python-json-logger?
thanks!!!
